# Simple MSAccess SQL UNION ALL; how to include an automatic annotation column value?

Tags: sql, ms-access, annotations, union-all

I’m pulling data from two separate tables (A, B) into another one (C ) in MSAccess using a SQL statement.  Appending all the columns from both feeding tables (A , B )  into the destination table (c ).  In order to annotate the data with the feeding source, I’m adding a ‘Source’ column to ( c ).  The annotation information in this ‘Source’ column does not exist in the feeding tables.  I want it to write the 'Source' entry from the value given in the SELECT statement.  This works correctly if I was loading just one table but it doesn't working when I use a UNION ALL to load multiple tables at a time.  The below code results in a entry prompt for the 'Source' value which is applied to all entries.  What am I doing wrong?

`INSERT INTO Hist_PO (Plant, Material_No, Date_Delivery, Quantity_Ordered, Quantity_Recieved, Source)
SELECT Plant, Material, [Delivery date], [Scheduled Quantity], [Quantity delivered], “”
FROM (
SELECT Plant, Material, [Delivery date], [Scheduled Quantity], [Quantity delivered], "Source_A"
FROM [Table_A]
UNION ALL
SELECT Plant, Material, [Delivery date], "Source_B"
FROM [Table_B]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...  SAP_Instance labeled with [banana] entries.

```
INSERT INTO [Test-Table] ( Material_No, Date_Delivery, SAP_Instance )
SELECT Material, [Delivery date], [banana]
FROM (SELECT Material, [Delivery date], 'SAP_EU' as [banana]

FROM [PO-ME80FN-EU]

UNION ALL

SELECT Material, [Delivery date], 'SAP_NAM'  as [banana]

FROM [PO-ME80FN-NAM]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query- for union, your select statements should have equal no of columns

```
INSERT INTO Hist_PO (Plant, Material_No, Date_Delivery, Quantity_Ordered, Quantity_Recieved, Source)
SELECT Plant, Material, [Delivery date], [Scheduled Quantity], [Quantity delivered], source 
FROM 
(
SELECT Plant, Material, [Delivery date], [Scheduled Quantity], [Quantity delivered], "Source_A"  as source FROM [Table_A]
UNION ALL
SELECT Plant, Material, [Delivery date],0,0 "Source_B" FROM [Table_B]
)
```